# get the index of a tal:repeat in another tal:repeat function

Tags: plone, zope, chameleon, template-tal

As you can see I have 3 lists: `Procedur_Headers`, `Diagnoses` and `List_Procedur`. 
`Procedur_headers` gives the headers of my tabels,
`Diagnoses` gives the specific id of a procedure and
`List_Procedur` is a list of lists (query’s) where all the data that I need is contained.
Now what I want to do is to have the index of the Diagnoses page in the

```
tal:repeat="list_procedur List_Procedur[index]"
```

that I can get my data in my table.
I already can get the index:

```
tal:content="python:repeat['diagnoses'].index"
```

but I can't do this at the place of index.
Does anybody have a solution for something like this?

```
<table id="tableIngrepen" class="table">
    <thead class="header">
    <tr>
        <th>Code Diagnose vast</th>
        <th tal:repeat="procedur_headers Procedur_Headers" tal:content="procedur_headers" > </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr tal:repeat="diagnoses Diagnoses"> 
        <td tal:content="python:repeat['diagnoses'].index"></td>
        <td ><input type='text' id="dz_code" class="input-mini" value="${diagnoses.code_diagnose}" onchange="voegrijtoe_Ingrepen(this.value,this);logging(this,'Code','2')" placeholder="Code"></input></td> <!-- onfocus="rijencolom($(this).parent().children().index($(this)),$(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent()))" -->
        <td colspan="6">
            <table  id="tableIngrepen" class="table table-hover" style="border-style:none">
                <thead class="header">
                    <tr>
                        <th tal:repeat="procedur_headers Procedur_Headers" tal:content="procedur_headers" > </th> <!-- style="display:none"-->
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr tal:repeat="list_procedur List_Procedur[index]">
                    <td style="max-width: 60px; word-wrap: break-word" >Uitleg over de Code van deze diagnose in maximaal 200 karakters</td>
                    <td ><input type='text' id="dz_Datum" class="input-small2" value="${list_procedur.code_diagnose}"  onchange="logging(this,'Datum','2');datumvalidate(this)" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"></input></td>
                    <td><input type='text' id="dz_dir" class="input-mini1"  onchange="logging(this,'Dir','2')" ></input></td>
                    <td><input type='text' id="dz_aan" class="input-mini1"  onchange="logging(this,'Aan','2')" ></input></td>
                    <td><input type='text' id="dz_uit" class="input-mini1"  onchange="logging(this,'Dz','2')" ></input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="max-width: 60px; word-wrap: break-word" >Uitleg over de Code van deze diagnose in maximaal 200 karakters</td>
                    <td ><input type='text' id="dz_Datum" class="input-small2"  onchange="logging(this,'Datum','2');datumvalidate(this)" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"></input></td>
                    <td><input type='text' id="dz_dir" class="input-mini1"  onchange="logging(this,'Dir','2')" ></input></td>
                    <td><input type='text' id="dz_aan" class="input-mini1"  onchange="logging(this,'Aan','2')" ></input></td>
                    <td><input type='text' id="dz_uit" class="input-mini1"  onchange="logging(this,'Dz','2')" ></input></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can't you do just:

<tr tal:repeat="diagnoses Diagnoses"> 
        <div tal:omit="True" tal:define="myindex python:repeat['diagnoses'].index">

..use the myindex..

</div>
</tr>

?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!! Works like a charm :) the only thing that not work is the tal:omit="True" I left this out and everything works.

Comment: ops, it is tal:omit-tag="", True is being interpreted as a value from tal...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is:

```
<tr tal:repeat="diagnoses Diagnoses"> <div tal:omit-tag="" tal:define="myindex python:repeat['diagnoses'].index"> ..use the myindex.. </div> </tr>
```